Asymptotic volume of intersection of n-cube with n-sphere
I would like to symbolically compute the following:
$$\lim_{d\to\infty} \frac{\text{Vol}(C^d(1) \cap B^d(K\sqrt{d}))}{\text{Vol}(C^d(1))}$$
where $B^d(r) = \{(x_1, \dots, x_d) \mid x_1^2 + \dots + x_d^2 = r^2\}$, $C^d(r) = [-r, r]^d$, and $0 < K< 2$ is a constant.
How can I use Mathematica to solve this symbolically?

Welcome to MA.SE. You have to show your attempt of solution.

I doubt that fully automatic proof is possible with MA. However, one can  imagine that the answer is 0 for $K=0$, and 1 for $K>0$.

Using angles $\theta$ indexed by their power in the volume element with radius $r$ and equatorial angle $\phi$
   vars = {r, 
      Sequence @@ Array[(Subscript[\[Theta], 8 - #] &), {6}, 2], \[Phi]}

$$\left\{r,\theta _6,\theta _5,\theta _4,\theta _3,\theta _2,\theta _1,\phi \right\}$$
The volume form coefficient in hyperspherical coordinates yields
    vol = CoordinateChartData[{"Hyperspherical", "Euclidean", 8}, 
      "VolumeFactor",  vars] 

$$r^7 \sin \theta _1 \ \sin ^2 \theta _2 \ \sin ^3 \theta _3 \ \sin ^4 \theta _4 \ \sin ^5 \theta _5 \ \sin ^6 \theta _6$$
The ranges are $(0,\pi)$ for all polar altidude angles $\theta_i$ and $0,2\pi$ for the azimuth along the full greatest circle, the equator
  ranges = 
  Sequence @@ ( 
  CoordinateChartData[{"Hyperspherical", "Euclidean", 8}, 
                      "CoordinateRangeAssumptions", vars] /. 
   {r > 0 :> {r, 0, 1}, a_ < x_ < b_ | a_ < x_ <= b_ :> {x, a, b}})

$$\text{Sequence}\left[\{r,0,1\},\left\{\theta _6,0,\pi \right\},\left\{\theta _5,0,\pi \right\},\left\{\theta _4,0,\pi \right\},\left\{\theta _3,0,\pi \right\},\left\{\theta _2,0,\pi \right\},\left\{\theta _1,0,\pi \right\},\{\phi ,-\pi ,\pi \}\right]$$
  Integrate[vol, ranges ]

$$\frac{\pi ^4}{24}$$
With   the factor $2\pi $ the volume is the product of
  Assuming[n >= 2,    
     2 Pi Product[Integrate[Sin[\[Theta]]^k, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}], 
            {k, 1,  n - 2}]]

$$\frac{2 \pi ^{n/2}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}$$
